# how to return values on slide change using slid.bs.carousel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4's Carousel with jQuery and php to make an odometer.  The value of the odometer dynamically changes on each slide.  I intend to use .addClass depending on length of the value.

My issue is when I console.log my value, only the value from the first slide is repeatedly printed. The upside is that it at least prints on slide change.

How do I console.log the value unique to it's current slide, and console.log the subsequent values and their slides? I figure if I can see the values are actually printing to their corresponding slides, the code I have so far should work in terms of checking length and eventually use addClass and removeClass with if statements.

php

```
<div class="carousel-item <?php if ($z==0) { echo 'active';} ?>">
     <div class="stats-wrapper">
          <div class="Count" data-value="<?php echo $number?>">
            0
          </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

jquery

```
function charsAlign() {

    var numCheck = $('.Count').data('value');           
    var makeStr = numCheck.toString();

    console.log(makeStr);   

    if(makeStr.length === 5){
        console.log(makeStr);
    }
    else {
        console.log('dont have 5'); 
    };  
}

$('#stat-carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', charsAlign);
```

Comment: You should use $(".count").get(index).data('value'); or $(".count").get(index).attr("data-value");. The class in css will return as array. you could try by console.log($(".count")); refer to this documentation https://api.jquery.com/get/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just Update your CSS selector:** (See CSS Selectors:https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

```
  var numCheck = $('.active .Count').data('value');
```